# Error:Invalid login 535 5.0.0 authentication failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, icalendar, nodemailer

I am trying to do outlook calender event for that i used mailing service and i am using express frame work and mongoose queries in my project

Here is my code below:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var Outlook = require('./outlook.model');

var icalToolkit = require('ical-toolkit');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
//Create a iCal object
var builder = icalToolkit.createIcsFileBuilder();
builder.method = 'REQUEST';
builder.events.push({    

  //Event start time, Required: type Date() 
  start: new Date(),

  //Event end time, Required: type Date() 
  end: new Date(),
  });
//builder.method = meeting.method;
//Add the event data

var icsFileContent = builder.toString();
var smtpOptions = {
    "secureConnection": true,
    "from": "******",
    "host": "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
    "secureConnection": true,
    "port": 587,
    "transportMethod": "SMTP",
    "auth": {
        user: '******',
        pass: '******'
    }
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport(smtpOptions));

var mailOptions = {
    from: '*******',
    to: '******',
    subject: 'Meeting to attend',
    html: "Anything here",

    text: "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii",
    alternatives: [{
        contentType: 'text/calendar; charset="utf-8"; method=REQUEST',
        content: icsFileContent.toString()
    }]
};

//send mail with defined transport object 
exports.send = function(req, res) {
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
        }
    });
};
```

And when i am doing this i am getting 200 success message and after that i am getting an error saying

```
    {[Error:Invalid login:535 5.0.0 Authentication Failed]
code:'EAUTH'
response:'535 5.0.0 Authentication Failed',
responseCode:535,
command:'AUTH PLAIN'
}
```

I have no idea about this error 
any help is highly appreciated ..!

Answer (score 0):

This is a target e-mail server response, saying that `authentication failed` when you send an e-mail to it. Perhaps you're trying to send an e-mail to the server, which requires authentication, and your user or pass is wrong. Refer to `RFC 822` to find out what  exactly the return code `535` means.